# Detectar si una palabra es palíndroma usando con punteros

Tags: c++, punteros, booleano, paso-por-referencia, char

Tengo que comprobar si una palabra es un palíndromo, y esto lo tengo que hacer con punteros, tengo el siguiente código, y al imprimir la palabra normal si lo hace, pero al tratar de hacerlo en el segundo `for` ya no imprime la palabra al revés bien, sino que no imprime nada:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

bool esPalindrome(char *ptrPalabra, int size){
    int aux;
    char palindromeAux1[size], 
    palindromeAux2[size];
    char *ptrAux;
    ptrPalabra = ptrPalabra;
    for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
        palindromeAux1[i] = *(ptrPalabra+i);
    }
    ptrPalabra = ptrPalabra+size;
    for(int j=size;j>=0;j--){
        palindromeAux2[j] = *(ptrPalabra+j);
    }
    for(int a=0;a<=size;a++){
        cout<<palindromeAux1[a];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int b=0;b<=size;b++){
        cout<<palindromeAux2[b];
    }
    return true;
}

int main(){
    string palabraAux;
    cout<<"Ingrese una palabra:\n";
    cin>>palabraAux;
    char palindrome[palabraAux.length()];
    strcpy(palindrome,palabraAux.c_str());
    esPalindrome(palindrome, palabraAux.length());
    return 0;
}
```

Esta es otra versión del código con lo que lo he intentado pero aun no me da nada (NOTA: tiene que ser con la función `bool`, realmente solo es un prototipo porque lo que necesito realmente es verificar si una palabra es un palíndromo o no)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

bool esPalindrome(char *ptrPalabra, int size){
    char *ptrAux;

    for(int j=0;j<=size;j++){
        *ptrAux = *(ptrPalabra+j);
        ptrAux++;
        ptrPalabra--;
    }
    cout<<ptrAux+2<<endl;

    return true;
}

int main(){
    string palabraAux;
    cout<<"Ingrese una palabra:\n";
    cin>>palabraAux;
    char palindrome[palabraAux.length()];
    strcpy(palindrome,palabraAux.c_str());
    esPalindrome(palindrome, palabraAux.length());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar si la palabra ingresada es palíndromo no tienes por qué copiar el `string` en un `char[]`. A través de `c_str()` puedes obtener los punteros al inicio y al final de la cadena. Una vez tienes los punteros, iteras a través de la cadena y ya lo tienes

```
bool esPalindrome(std::string const& palabra)
{
    char const* inicio = palabra.c_str();
    char const* fin = palabra.c_str() + palabra.length() - 1;

    bool palindromo = true;
    for (;inicio<fin && palindromo; ++inicio, --fin)
    {
        palindromo = *inicio == *fin;
    }

    return palindromo;
}
```

El problema que tiene, por ejemplo, este bucle tuyo:

```
for(int j=size;j>=0;j--)
```

Es que `palabra[size]` apunta al caracter finalizador de cadena `0`. Si pones este caracter al inicio de la cadena, entonces no se imprimirá nada porque ese caracter le dice a la función de C++ que la cadena termina ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no debería funcionar o si funciona puede hacerlo de manera errática pues estás usando una característica que no es estándar: "*Arreglos<sup>1</sup> de Tamaño Variable*" (ATV) ([*Variable Length Array* en inglés](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla)).

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (y en otros lenguajes, como por ejemplo [c](/questions/tagged/c)) los arreglos necesitan tener un tamaño que se conozca en tiempo de compilación, sin embargo tú les estás dando un tamaño que se conoce en tiempo de ejecución:

```
bool esPalindrome(char *ptrPalabra, int size){
//                                      ^^^^ <-- Variable: se conoce en tiempo de ejecución
    int aux;
    char palindromeAux1[size], 
//                      ^^^^ <-- Variable: se conoce en tiempo de ejecución
    palindromeAux2[size];
//                 ^^^^ <-- Variable: se conoce en tiempo de ejecución
```

```
string palabraAux;
cout<<"Ingrese una palabra:\n";
cin>>palabraAux;
char palindrome[palabraAux.length()];
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Retorno de una función miembro de una variable, se conoce en tiempo de ejecución
```

Si necesitas un arreglo de tamaño variable deberás usar memoria dinámica:

```
bool esPalindrome(char *ptrPalabra, int size){
//                                      ^^^^ <-- Variable: se conoce en tiempo de ejecución
    int aux;
    char *palindromeAux1 new char[size];
//  Memoria dinámica --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    char *palindromeAux2 = new char[size];
//    Memoria dinámica --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
string palabraAux;
cout<<"Ingrese una palabra:\n";
cin>>palabraAux;
char *palindrome new char[palabraAux.length()];
//   Memoria dinámica --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Pero esto es complicarse de más, si quieres comprobar si una palabra es palíndromo no tienes que copiar la palabra en otra formación ni recorrer la palabra entera. Usa la función `std::string::c_str` que devuelve un puntero de sólo lectura y recorre simultáneamente la palabra desde los extremos haciendo comparaciones:

```
bool esPalindrome(const char *palabra, int longitud) {

    for (int indice = 0; indice != longitud / 2; ++indice) {
        const char *izquierda = palabra + indice;
        const char *derecha = palabra + longitud - indice - 1;

        if (*izquierda != *derecha)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    string palabraAux;
    cout << "Ingrese una palabra:\n";
    cin >> palabraAux;

    cout << palabraAux << " es palindromo? "
        << esPalindrome(palabraAux.c_str(), palabraAux.length());

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFLTsMwEF0npxjKJiFtKSxJGsSSHQdAQq4zSS054@CPhECcPYzbpmnZWc/vNzNyGFZSC@rG8VaR1KFBqJRx3qLo63TGGFHU1Wm6M0YDujehFTXW9JhJQ86D3AsLd4PQYmfFEhR50IY65UOTw0@aJq2xkEWYdUoibGFTTu@b7ZkM9/BYQlEcf6I0SS4T1PdnUGgbwQanNChOPuU/boMW@XXFPOespvAVPJTcL1EtZBf23GkyyPk3seiDJWiFdjHolyUnyNvACANxul4oyg61g@ONAYke3SA4x/km5hw3OTV6CV9sJk3wUFWweKXOokMIJCbG0zstIkUR1PWVbNbN6MGF7xOh44HMMwOMXt1sFqzlBzfK8uWFyVojdX6f5Xk5T7nhEceR92HISLTpHw)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocido como *formación* o *array* en inglés.